# Get text of previous header in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I have a HTML which looks like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Some additional content, can be multiple, various tags</p>
<h2><a id="123"></a>Foo</h2>
<p>Some additional content, can be multiple, various tags</p>
<h3><a id="456"></a>Bar</h3>
```

Now, for each anchor with id, I want to find out the header hierarchy, e.g. for the anchor with `id="123"` I would like to get something like `[{level: 1, title: "Title"}, {level: 2, title: "Foo"}]`, similarly for anchor with `id="456"`, I would like to get `[{level: 1, title: "Title"}, {level: 2, title: "Foo"}, {level: 3, title: "Bar"}]`.

My code looks like this so far:

```js
const linkModel: IDictionary<ILinkModelEntry> = {};
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
$("a").each((_i, elt) => {
    const anchor = $(elt);
    const id = anchor.attr().id;
    if (id) {
        const parent = anchor.parent();
        const parentTag = parent.prop("tagName");
        let headerHierarchy: any[] = [];
        if (["H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6"].includes(parentTag)) {
            let level = parseInt(parentTag[1]);
            headerHierarchy = [{level, text: parent.text()}];
            level--;
            while (level > 0) {
                const prevHeader = parent.prev("h" + level);
                const text = prevHeader.text();
                headerHierarchy.unshift({level, text});
                level--;
            }
        }
        linkModel["#" + id] = {originalId: id, count: count++, headerHierarchy};
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong, since

```js
const prevHeader = parent.prev("h" + level);
const text = prevHeader.text();
```

always returns an empty string (i.e. `""`)?

Comment: You can do this with `closest()`, but really you want to iterate from the `h1`'s down. Going back up the tree is a sign that you're not being very efficient.

Comment: You mean to use `const prevHeader = parent.closest("h" + level);` instead of `.prev`? Doesn't seem to work either...
Your suggestion would be to iterate over each header level and find the anchors below the respective header level? Haven't thought about the implementation that much yet, but I presume that the implementation could get very messy... (not that my current implementation is very clean...)

Comment: In the example, the closest header would be: `$(elt).closest('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').first()`

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get the whole hierarchy?
E.g. for `<h2>Foo</h2><h3><a id="1"></a><a id="2"></a><a id="3"></a>Bar</h3>` this will always return `Bar`, but not `Foo` (using `.closest("h2")` on `$(elt)` does not work)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to capture hierarchy. If your example had another `<h1>` followed by more `<h2>` and `<h3>`s below it, you'd want to pop the stack of parents back down to that new `<h1>` level for linking future `<h2>` and `<h3>` children rather than have an array of all elements back up to that first `<h1>Title</h1>`.

Here's one approach:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Some additional content, can be multiple, various tags</p>
<h2><a id="123"></a>Foo</h2>
<p>Some additional content, can be multiple, various tags</p>
<h3><a id="456"></a>Bar</h3>
<h1>Another Title</h1>
<h2><a id="xxx"></a>Foo 2</h2>
<h3><a id="yyy"></a>Bar 2</h3>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = {};
const stack = [];

[...$("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")].forEach(e => {
  const level = +$(e).prop("tagName")[1];

  while (stack.length && level <= stack.at(-1).level) {
    stack.pop();
  }

  if (!stack.length || level >= stack.at(-1).level) {
    stack.push({level, title: $(e).text()});
  }

  if ($(e).has("a[id]").length) {
    const id = $(e).find("a[id]").attr("id");
    result[`#${id}`] = [...stack];
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```js
{
  '#123': [ { level: 1, title: 'Title' }, { level: 2, title: 'Foo' } ],
  '#456': [
    { level: 1, title: 'Title' },
    { level: 2, title: 'Foo' },
    { level: 3, title: 'Bar' }
  ],
  '#xxx': [
    { level: 1, title: 'Another Title' },
    { level: 2, title: 'Foo 2' }
  ],
  '#yyy': [
    { level: 1, title: 'Another Title' },
    { level: 2, title: 'Foo 2' },
    { level: 3, title: 'Bar 2' }
  ]
}
```

If you actually want the whole chain of ancestors linearly back to the first, then remove the `while` loop (unlikely your intent).